# How to read PDFs in Android without using third-party apps, or a webview?

Tags: android, pdf

I want to write an Android application to read and display PDFs. I don't want to use any third-party applications to do this, because I don't want to force my users to download those applications.  And I don't want to use a webview, because then users won't be able to use my app when they're offline.

How might I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link I used to create one that mostly works.

It outlines how to write (and hence read) all the common PDF parts that are in a .pdf file. It's far more readable than the ISO spec, especially if you haven't done PDF formats before.

http://www.adobe.com/technology/pdfs/presentations/KingPDFTutorial.pdf

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you fancy building a PDF rendering engine from scratch (or including one in your project), you probably are better with using some kind of intent to ask some other application on the phone to view the PDF. I know you do not really want the requirement of having an application installed to handle it, but I suggest that you are probably adding unnecessary complexity to your application by trying to do it some other way.

It's worth mentioning that quite a lot of Android handsets already have PDF viewers preinstalled, and incidentally, I think even WebView requires that the phone has a PDF viewer installed!